# img not displaying correctly in horizontal nav

Tags: html, css, menu, nav

Im putting together a horizontal footer nav for a website that I am working on, but for the life in me I cannot get it to display correctly.

Basically what I am looking to achieve is for each menu item to be displayed with an image to the left go the link text with the text centred in relation to the middle of the image.

I know this is a simple problem, but everything I've tried to resolve the problem doesnt seem to work.

CSS

```
#footer-links{ border: 1px solid black; height:90px; width:100%;}

#footer-links .nav-bar { list-style:none;}

#footer-links .nav-bar li { display:inline; padding: 0 10px; }

#footer-links .nav-bar li a {
padding-left: 115px; /* Create padding on the left where the icon goes */
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #333;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;}


.nav-bar .nav-button-developments a { background:url("http://mulgraveproperties.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/icon11.jpg") no-repeat 0px -2px transparent; }

.nav-bar .nav-button-news a { background:url("http://mulgraveproperties.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/icon21.jpg") no-repeat 0px -2px transparent;  }

.nav-bar .nav-button-contact a { background:url("http://mulgraveproperties.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/icon31.jpg") no-repeat 0px -2px transparent; }
```

HTML

```
<nav id="footer-links">
     <ul class="nav-bar">
          <li class="nav-button-developments"><a href="http://www.mulgraveproperties.co.uk/index.php/our-developments/">Our Developments</a></li>
          <li class="nav-button-news"><a href="http://www.mulgraveproperties.co.uk/index.php/category/news/">News</a></li>
          <li class="nav-button-contact"><a href="http://www.mulgraveproperties.co.uk/index.php/contact-2/">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is a link to the associated

http://jsfiddle.net/n420jmsw/

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: Updated JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/n420jmsw/2/ I have update based on my understandings from your comment

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shanidkv, but they are displaying stacked not horizontally and when I change #footer-links .nav-bar li to inline from block it doesnt change to horizontal.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? I'm seeing text and images inline and centered.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to get it right but what about a float ? http://jsfiddle.net/n420jmsw/3/

```
#footer-links .nav-bar li { padding: 0 10px;float:left; }
```